# What is exact difference Between unrolled Linklist & Vlist?

Tags: linked-list

I found few forum entries mentioning that Vlist can hold variable number of element at each node, but I think, it's also possible with unrolled linklist.

Like

```
unrolled link list  node {
     node next,      
     int numElements,
     array elements ,
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, cheers and other chit-chat have no place in question (read help-tour). Format your code by indenting it with 4 spaces ( or select code followed by Ctrl+K)

Answer (score 0):

Both `VList`'s and `unrolled linked list`s are very similar. The key difference is that `VList`'s store a pointer to a root node that contains some n data elements and a pointer to a next node that then contains n/2 elements and a pointer to another next node that contains n/4 elements, and so on.

`unrolled linked list`'s on the other hand contain a root node which then contains both a pointer to the next node, and an array of data elements along with the number of elements in the node, up to a pre-defined maximum.

In C/C++, some examples of structs for these data structures (if you wanted to store `int`s) might be the following:

```
struct vlist_node {
  list_node *next;
  int array[];        //(n/2) elems at root, then (n/4), (n/8), ...
};

struct unrolled_list_node {
  unrolled_list_node *next;
  int array[];     //contains numElements ints
  int numElements; //up to MAX_ELEMS
};
```